# Authentication for foxx APIs

Tags: authentication, arangodb, foxx

I am working on ArangoDB 3.1 in stand-alone mode.
We are creating a Foxx API to authenticate the users who are accessing our database and our custom APIs. In order to activate authentication, we added the following statements in the arangod.conf file.

```
authentication = true
authentication-system-only = true
```

We created a user in arangosh for the database we are working on. When we log into the web console the username and password worked and we are able to access the database,APIs and also able to create users using the APIs.

But when we try to access using another browser or using curl command we are not able to see the user information. HTTP and curl commands are given below.

`http://username:password@ip-address:portno/_db/AdtheorentDB/test-app/whoami`

`curl --basic --user "username:password" -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://ip-address:portno/_db/databasename/test-app/whoami'`

What might be the issue ?
The above curl command is obtained from the link given below.
[ArangoDB authentication via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463324/arangodb-authentication-via-http)

Comment: Could you show an example of what the `whoami` route looks like? From the description it's not quite clear whether you're trying to implement your own authentication or use ArangoDB's built-in authentication.

Comment: router.get('/whoami', function (req, res) {
  try {
    const user = users.document(req.session.uid);
    res.send({username: user.username});
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({username: null});
  }
})
.description('Returns the currently active username.');
We were trying to emulate the authentication example given by arangodb